# R: How to convert a vector into matrix without replicating the vector?

Tags: r

Here's my problem:
I have a vector and I want to convert it into a matrix with fixed number of columns, but I don't want to replicate the vector to fill the matrix when it's necessary.
For example:
My vector has a length of 15, and I want a matrix with 4 columns.I wish to get the matrix wit 15 elements from the vector and a 0 for the last element in the matrix.
How can I do this?

Edit:
Sorry for not stating the question clearly and misguiding you guys with my example. In my program,**I don't know the length of my vector, it depends on other parameters and this question involves with a loop, so I need a general solution that can solve many different cases, not just my example.**
Thanks for answering.

Comment: assuming that the vector you have is `letters[1:15]`: `matrix(c(letters[1:15],0), ncol=4)` will give you a matrix with 4 columns

Comment: `x <- 1:15; m <- matrix(x, ncol = 4); m[-seq_along(x)] <- 0` maybe

Comment: @AdamQuek Thanks for answering.  Actually that example is not quite clear ( my bad for not stating the question clearly). In my program, I don't know the length of my vector, so I cannot fill the matrix explicitly.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and also the code you have tried so far. Just stating "involves with a loop" is too vague. Show us what is your expected output as well.

Comment: For example:
I need to discretize my time to some numerical method application.
Let Tmax be my time span, and h0 be my initial step size.
I need two step size: coarse one and fine one, here's the code:
`h_coarse=h0*M^(-L+1)
h_fine=h0*M^(-L)
N_fine=round(Tmax/h_fine)
N_coarse=round(Tmax/h_coarse)
`
Then I need to generate a Brownian Motion path, and sum finer grids up to get coarse grids. I would like to use a matrix and an 'apply' function. And that's why I ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subset your vector to a multiple of the number of columns (so as to include all the elements). This will add necessary amount of `NA` to the vector. Then convert to matrix.

```
x = 1:15
matrix(x[1:(4 * ceiling(length(x)/4))], ncol = 4)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14
#[3,]    3    7   11   15
#[4,]    4    8   12   NA
```

If you want to replace NA with 0, you can do so using `is.na()` in another step

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with `dim<-` and `length<-`

```
n <- 4
n1 <- ceiling(length(x)/n)
`dim<-`(`length<-`(x, n*n1), c(n1, n))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14
#[3,]    3    7   11   15
#[4,]    4    8   12   NA
```

#### data

```
x <- 1:15
```

Comment: there's a typo: it should be c(n1,n)